# Python Selenium - 'WebElement'object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, post

I am trying to get the URLs of all the posts on the page so I can open them in another tab,
can someone please help thx!

```
def opening(self):
    bot = self.bot
    bot.maximize_window()
    bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+hashtag+'/')
    time.sleep(2)

def posts(self):
    bot = self.bot
    hrefs = bot.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    pic_hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs]
    pic_hrefs = [href for href in pic_hrefs if hashtag in href]
    time.sleep(1)
    print(hashtag +' pictures: ' + len(pic_hrefs))
```

I am a beginner so please don't make fun of me and thank you for everyone that helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [this article on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please add the stack trace for the error you received to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
hrefs = bot.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
```

returns a selenium web element. It is not a list, or any other *iterable* element. In other words, you won't be able to iterate through it with your *for loop*. Print it and you'll see what it is. Use this line instead, which will return a list. Note that I added an *s*.

```
hrefs = bot.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Also, did you make a typo in `href`? Shouldn't it be `hrefs`? The last instance in there:

```
pic_hrefs = [href for href in pic_hrefs if hashtag in href]
```